# Alternative proof of Sylvester’s Theorem

Tags: linear-algebra

In linear algebra we just approached Sylvester’s Theorem:

*”Let $b:V^2 \to \mathbb{R}$ be a bilinear symmetric form and let $B$ be a diagonalizing base for $b$. The number of positive terms of the diagonal of the associated matrix doesn’t depend upon the choice of $B$*

After reading the proof on my book, I thought about a possible approach(or at least I hope so) for another proof.

**My attempt of proof**

Let $B,\bar{B}$ be 2 diagonalizing bases of $b$. And let $M,\bar{M}$ be the respective matrixes associated to $b$. Clearly:
$$\bar{M}=PMP^t$$
Where $P$ is the change of basis matrix.Since $P$ is an isomorphism it can be expressed as product of elementary matrixes(corresponding to elementary transformations on the rows):
$$\bar{M}=E_{\mathcal{R_n}}\cdot …E_{\mathcal{R_1}}\cdot M \cdot E_{\mathcal{C_1}}\cdot...\cdot E_{\mathcal{C_n}}$$

Where $\mathcal{C_i}$ is the elementary column transformation relative associated to $\mathcal{R_i}$. Since the matrix product is associative we can just prove this with $n=1$ then the procedure is inductive.
$$E_{\mathcal{R_1}}\cdot M \cdot E_{\mathcal{C_1}}$$
There are 3 cases.

**Row switching transformation**

In this case two terms of the diagonal get switched: this clearly doesn’t modify the number of positive terms.

**Row multiplication transformation**

In this case an element of the diagonal gets multiplied two times by the same scalar $c$( so basically $c^2$).Since $c^2>0$ the sign of the element doesn’t change.

**Row addition transformation**

Here I’m having difficulties.Maybe I should prove before that this kind of transformation is useless.

Is this an intelligent approach or is it unproductive or incorrect ?

Comment: I don't understand what you're trying to prove, as there is no reason for $E_{\mathscr R_i} \cdot M \cdot E_{\mathscr C_i}$ to be diagonal.

Comment: @PseudoNeo for this reason I said that maybe I should prove before that  row additions are unnecessary(because in the other cases that matrix is diagonal).

Comment: but they are necessary (in a way, they are the most important ones), it's just that you need more than one to go from a diagonal matrix to another one (stupid analogy: in chess, a king can go from a white square to a white square, but it cannot do that in just one move). So your global plan is hard to implement.

Comment: why are they necessary? i can rearrange row(with row switching) so that positive, negative and null elememts are in the right place and then I can use row multiplication to modify the value of the diagonal element in each row. Can you give me an example in which they are necessary?

Comment: A way to make it work would be to define something that makes sense for any matrix, and boils down to the number of positive diagonal coefficients when the matrix happens to be diagonal. If you had such a generalisation, you could try to analyse the three kinds of operations, and prove they don't change your generalised invariant. The proof I know of Sylvester's inertia law actually does that: make sense more generally of this number of positive diagonal coefficients (it's the max. dimension of a subspace on which the quadratic form is positive); it doesn't use the operations, though.